# Does every unbounded countable ordinal have an unbounded sequence?

Tags: ordinals

Let $S$ be a countable well-ordered set which is unbounded (i.e. it has no maximum). Does there exist an unbounded increasing sequence in $S$?

Comment: Are you asking if every countable ordinal does, or if there is some countable ordinal which does?

Comment: Thanks, I meant does every countable ordinal...?

Comment: Take $\omega + 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the example but indeed this is not what I wanted. Archimedean was not a proper term that I used here...

Comment: $\omega + 1$ is a countable ordinal, and equivalently $0, 1, 2, \dotsc, \omega$ is well-ordered but does not contain an unbounded increasing sequence since $\omega$ is an upper bound for the whole sequence.

Comment: I edited the question. This is what I meant.

Comment: Your title is about ordinals, while your question is about well-ordered sets. It doesn't matter for this question, but it would be better to make the question and the title agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: let $f : \omega \to S$ enumerate $S$. Starting at $1$, remove $i$ from the domain of $f$ if $f(i) < f(j)$ for some $j < i$. The result is an unbounded partial function from $\omega$ to $S$, which you can convert into  a sequence by renumbering the arguments.

Comment: Nice solution. It works for any totally ordered countable set.

Answer (score 0):

I found a related question which answers this question too.

[A generalization of "any countable limit ordinal is the union of a sequence of increasing ordinal"](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1240160/a-generalization-of-any-countable-limit-ordinal-is-the-union-of-a-sequence-of-i)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Let $s_1$ be an element of $S$. Because $S$ is unbounded, $s_1$ can't be the maximum element. Therefore, there exists at least one element of $S$ greater than $s_1$. Call this element $s_2$. $S$ also can't have $s_2$ as its maximum element, so there must be an element of $S$ (call it $s_3$) greater than $s_2$.

Repeat this process ad infinitum, and you have an unbounded increasing sequence.

Comment: It is not necessarily unbounded. It is possible that some element of $S$ is greater than all the elements of the sequence.